# How to write accessor expression to infer the type?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, extension-methods

Given the following code

```
[Table("Bar")]
public class Foo {
  [Column("BarID")]
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
public static class MyExtensions {
  public static string TableName(this Type type) {
    var attrib = type.GetCustomAttribute<TableAttribute>(false);
    return attrib?.Name ?? type.Name;
  }
  public static string ColumnName<TType, TMember>(this Type t, Expression<Func<TType, TMember>> accessor) {
    var member = accessor.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (member != null) {
      var field = member.Member;
      var attrib = field.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>();
      return attrib?.Name ?? field.Name;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I can then write code like `typeof(Foo).TableName();` to get the table name

For the column name I can use `typeof(Foo).ColumnName((Foo f) => f.Id)`

How can I get the ColumnName extension method to infer TType in the accessor expression so that I can simply code as `type(Foo).ColumnName(f => f.Id)`

Comment: Your second method doesn't use `t`... It's not really extending Type at all (it is in the sense that it'll actually get called from a type object, but you don't use its value). Generic Type parameters can't be substituted directly from a type object. The only way you'll get something generic is to take the type and create a generic method definition using reflection but in that case you'd be stuck returning object (I think).. You could always have your extension method extend your entity types directly (`this MyEntity t`) and constrain the method to that `where MyEntity : EntityBase`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yes, I realized that. I just wanted to have the same api to get the ColumnAttribute value on the property. If the accessor approach does not work then I can create a method which can be called like 'typeof(Foo).ColumnName(nameof(Foo.Id))'

Comment: You can still go with the expression API to grab the member expression instead of nameof, the problem is creating the generic type argument from the type object without specifying the genric type directly. Since you already know Foo, why not supply it as part of the method call? `ColumnName<Foo, string>(f => f.Id)` and ditch the extension aspect for a normal static method with one parameter?

Comment: Though I guess in that case you wouldn't know string... You can combine the two approaches with a helper extension that creates a generic method using reflection, which then calls a version of the original. But I'm afraid you're going to have to specify your type *somewhere*... Though there could be some solution I'm completely over looking (it *is* 5am afterall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following

```
public static class Metadata<TType> {
  public static string TableName() {
    var type = typeof(TType);
    var attrib = type.GetCustomAttribute<TableAttribute>(false);
    return attrib?.Name ?? type.Name;
  }
  public static string ColumnName<TMember>(Expression<Func<TType, TMember>> propertyExpresseion) {
    if (propertyExpresseion.Body.NodeType != ExpressionType.MemberAccess) {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    var member = propertyExpresseion.Body as MemberExpression;
    var property = member.Member;
    var attrib = property.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>(false);
    return attrib?.Name ?? property.Name;
  }
}
```

which I can then use as

```
Metadata<Audit>.TableName();
Metadata<Audit>.ColumnName(a => a.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't even use the parameter `Type t` in the method, why does it even have to be an extension method?

```
public static string ColumnName<TType, TMember>(
    Expression<Func<TType, TMember>> accessor) { ... }
```

Usage:

```
ColumnName((Foo f) => f.Id)
```

This way the type is specified just once.